# What causes the wrong value read-out in a Pie menu value slider?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, pie-menu

Below you can see that the Normal size value is 737cm while it is actually only 37cm.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code - any idea if this is a bug or a mistake I did?

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mesh = context.active_object.data
    scene = context.scene

    pie = layout.menu_pie()      
    pie.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size", text="Size")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those numbers are really, unless i'm mistaken, the menu indices. The 7 isn't from the *normal_size*, but from the *index* of that pie-item. It's drawing the slider rather awkwardly close to the index. Leading me to believe pie menu's weren't intended to be used for drawing sliders, else it would be a common use case, and have a nice obvious solution. Maybe it does? someone will correct me if there is.

In any case it looks like the pie menus could be more thoroughly documented. I don't think it's a bug rather a misunderstanding of how to use it. It seems mostly geared towards toggling and executing operators.

The only way I know how to suppress the index is by making a row out of the slider.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mesh = context.active_object.data
    scene = context.scene

    pie = layout.menu_pie()

    row = pie.row()
    row.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size")
    pie.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face")
    pie.prop(mesh, "show_normal_loop")
    pie.prop(mesh, "show_normal_vertex")
    pie.prop(mesh, "show_faces")
    pie.prop(mesh, "show_edges")
```

[image]

All kinds of crazy things can be done with piemenus

#### Columns

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mesh = context.active_object.data
    scene = context.scene

    pie = layout.menu_pie()      
    col = pie.column()
    col.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face")
```

[image]

#### Rows

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mesh = context.active_object.data
    scene = context.scene

    pie = layout.menu_pie()      
    row = pie.row()
    row.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size")
    row = pie.row()        
    row.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face")
```

[image]

#### box

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    mesh = context.active_object.data
    scene = context.scene

    pie = layout.menu_pie()

    # option 1
    box = pie.box()
    col = box.column()
    col.prop(scene.tool_settings, "normal_size")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_normal_face")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_normal_loop")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_normal_vertex")

    # option 2
    box = pie.box()
    col = box.column()
    col.prop(mesh, "show_faces")
    col.prop(mesh, "show_edges")
```

[image]

Comment: I feel ashamed ... Thank you so much for you help. I got the feeling as well that the Pie menu concept is not yet fully refined to work with the general interface elements! I agree that the however the Pie Menu idea is pretty nice and what you can display in it so you do not have to use the main menu.